# Display points with lowest elevation within a 1m2 grid - QGIS 2.18.2

Tags: qgis, dem, tin, archaeology

I have a few thousand points measured with totalstation from an archaeological site. The points are measured quite unevenly which makes TIN triangulation and subsequent DEM generation a mess. Some areas has a lot of tightly measured points, others almost none.

I have created a 1m2 grid overlaying the points containing XYZ.

What I would like to achieve: Display one point for each 1m2 and that this one is the one with the lowest Z elevation value.

PS: Yes, the Z-values are negative, because the excavation was conducted on old seabed.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you are trying to do, but you may be interested in "Points Filter" function, which is in `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector point tools | Points filter`. This tool takes Point shapefile and its attribute (your Z) as input, and returns thinner point set. In this case you can filter it by **keep minima** option. Problem is, it takes points within a circle of defined radius, not the grid (square) as you have indicated. Just thought it may worth a try.

Comment: If what you are really trying to go is create an interpolated grid of elevation over the whole site then this isn't the right way to go about it...

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito it definitely thinned out the points in a reasonable way.

Comment: @Spacedman Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: anything from inverse distance weighting to kriging. These techniques draw strength from having lots of nearby points as that gives a better estimate of the elevation there, and also kriging lets you get a measure of the uncertainty on the elevation estimate of your predictions. Try not to use a particular tool (like generating a TIN) just because that's what your software has...

Comment: @Spacedman I did try out IDW and it looks much better. Thanks. I used to do this in Surfer but wanted to it open source now. I will give SAGA Kriging a go.